# How would you understand?

Tags: meaning, phrases, vocabulary, phrase-meaning

2 questions, wanted to check how would you understand and if it's correct to says so:

- kitchen backlog
- deli chronicles

Thanks!

Comment: Both make sense depending on what you’re trying to say.

Comment: A citchen backlog might apply to many orders for food which have not been prepared yet. Chronicles? Kitchen *records* perhaps, orders and deliveries *log*, health and safety procedures *file*. Chronicles seems more grandiose and historic.

Comment: Cool! Can kitchen backlog be used, when I want to express / say it's a list of receipts I want to try or list of food I want to taste in the future? So it's my kitchen backlog > all things that I plan to cook/prepare/try?